# Windows keeps spinning my disk every few minutes

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have a small home server that I use to host a minimal web application.
There is a SSD as the main disk and three HDDs as storage drives.

The HDDs are configured to go to sleep after 1min of inactivity.
The problem is : every ten minutes or so they wake up and spin for a short amount of time.

I'm concerned by this behavior since spinning up and down a drive tends to wear it out faster, at least from what i've heard. The noise they make is also a problem and that's why I would like to make them sleep as much as possible.

I tried the following steps :

- disable the very few programs installed
- disable all the services that can be related
- track scheduled tasks execution to find something related
- disable all the scheduled tasks that can be related
- set the drives as offline in the disk manager

None of these attempts were successful but it reduced the frequency of the problem (it used to happen every time i logged in via RDP, even with the disks marked as offline).

I used Process Monitor and the only activity that happened on the HDDs while the disk started spinning was some DeviceIoControl (ioctl).
The system regulary send SMART ioctl to all the disks.
Here is the list of commands :

- SMART_GET_VERSION
- SMART_SEND_DRIVE_COMMAND
- SMART_RCV_DRIVE_DATA

I guess these commands are the reason why the disk wake up.
They are sent through the "WMI Provider Host" aka wmiprvse.exe

I would really like to know the name of the coponent, task of service that send these requests.

I will probably try to make a Filter Device Driver in the next days to catch the SMART requests and let them pass at a reasonable pace, but even if it works, that would only be a workarround.

Comment: First of all, you're probably worrying about a non-issue. Any HDD that can be spun down is built with that possibility in mind and doing so, as designed, will not impact the longevity of said hardware. And yes, as you just found out, the simple SMART routine needs to 'wake up' the drives to check them. Again, **not a problem**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I've seen on many website (none of authority I admit) that it could harm them. The drives, juste like any product, are made for a reasonable use. There's a chance that this behavior was not considered a reasonable use by the engineers. Also, the noise they make is a problem and I would appreciate them to be quiet. I will edit the question to reflect this aspect of the problem.

Comment: Fighting with same problem for days now... tried disabling several services, crippling the os functionality, just to avoid windows from acessing my external drives (it's nonsese the quantity of processes that want to acess an LEAVE ALONE external drive!!!)